# Linear fit error for beta decay spectrum

Tags: mass, radiation, neutrinos, error-analysis, data-analysis

I'm trying to get an upper bound to the neutrino mass with kurie plot.
In order to do that I need to make a linear fit in order to get energy value that corresponds to $y=0$.
($y$ the kurie plot). The thing is, the range of the fit is rather arbitrary, and for each range I get slightly different values, so I was wondering on how to evaluate this error. Maybe something like making several fits for several ranges and take the range of the results as the added error?
Other suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: Could you provide a plot? I do not understand what you mean by "the range of the fit is rather arbitrary".

Comment: I dont have a plot at the moment, but you can think of a "wierd looking"  plot, that looks linear in some range, lets say from x=5 to x=10. but this "linearity range" is just something I chose from what is look to me as linear, while x=5.5 to x=9.5 could have been chosen by someone else leading to different result. The model doesnt specify this "linearity range" and therfore the range of the fit can lead to an error, which I would like to estimate

Answer (score 2):

A good general way to get insight into errors with curve fitting is called the bootstrap method. One fits repeatedly with random subsets of the data, noting the spread in the resulting fitted parameters.